# cloudfoundry vmc login error, system behind proxy

Tags: proxy, cloud-foundry

When I try to do vmc login
after providing user name and password, I get below error.

Problem with login to 'http://api.cloudfoundry.com', A connection attempt f
ailed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period o
f time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed
to respond. - connect(2), try again or register for an account.

But the curl api.cloudfoundry.com/info is successful.
even from browser I am able to access it fine.

I have my HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY set properly in environment variables.

Please help me in this regard, what should I be checking for this? Looks like vmc not going through proxy.

I have done the cloudfoundry setup at home and everything is smooth.
But when I try to do the same thing in office. I am facing this problem.

Comment: Do you get the same error running "vmc info"?

Comment: can you check the output from vmc -t login and see whether there is a problem communicating with api.cloudfoundry.com?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to verify if a proxy is being used it to add the `-t` option:

`$ vmc login -t`

This will show the HTTP request and response headers.